# Background worker process crashing

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, heroku, background-process

I'm creating a web app that takes username as input and perform some tasks with it. I'm using `flask` for the web and `heroku` to deploy it.I've two main python scripts these run the app. `app.py` and `task.py`. Everything is okey into my `app.py` file, where i used `flask` code for making the app but into my `task.py` file I've a

**Initialisation step**

```
from instabot import Bot
bot = Bot()
bot.login(username="myusername", password="mypassword")
```

now I deployed these script into the Procfile like

```
worker: python task.py
web: gunicorn app:app
```

but after deploying when i check it's log I'm getting

**logs**

```
2022-01-28T18:30:06.376795+00:00 
heroku[worker.1]: Starting process 
with command `python task.py`
        2022-01- 
28T18:30:07.081356+00:00 
heroku[worker.1]: State changed 
from starting to up
        2022-01- 
28T18:30:08.213687+00:00 
heroku[worker.1]: Process exited 
with status 0
        2022-01- 
28T18:30:08.274498+00:00 
heroku[worker.1]: State changed 
from up to crashed
```

as you can see it's getting **crashed**!! i don't know what's my mistake is can you please help me to figure out **: (**

Comment: I think your worker does not crash, just finish the execution. You need make your worker keep waiting to d the job. One exmple should be use python-rq to queue jobs from the main app to the worker. There are examples in the documentation https://python-rq.org/patterns/ (needs redis, that is available for free on Heroku)

Comment: Yeah ! After some searches i got that word "rq" everywhere but as I'm new on this field i don't know how to actually do that. thank you for providing me the source I'm gonna read it right now : )

Comment: Can you please write a code example for me how to do it : (

Comment: Are you really running this on Python 2.7 in the year 2022 CE?

Comment: nope! I'm on 3.10.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in my worker is almost stolen from the redis-rq documentation, with some changes to make it work also in our local development enviroment:

```py
import os
from rq import Queue, Connection
from tools import get_redis_store

# we need to use a different worker when we are in Heroku
if 'DYNO' in os.environ:
    from rq.worker import HerokuWorker as Worker
else:
    from rq import Worker

redis_url = os.getenv('REDIS_URL')
if not redis_url:
    raise RuntimeError('Set up Redis first.')

listen = ['default']

conn = get_redis_store()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Connection(conn):
        worker = Worker(map(Queue, listen))
        worker.work()
```

On tools.py

```py
_redis_store = None


def get_redis_store():
    '''
    Get a connection pool to redis based on the url configured
    on env variable REDIS_URL

    Returns
    -------
    redis.ConnectionPool
    '''
    global _redis_store
    if not _redis_store:
        redis_url = os.getenv('REDIS_URL')
        if redis_url:
            logger.debug('starting redis: %s ' % redis_url)
            if redis_url.startswith('rediss://'):
                # redis 6 encripted connection
                # heroku needs disable ssl verification
                _redis_store = redis.from_url(
                    redis_url, ssl_cert_reqs=None)
            else:
                _redis_store = redis.from_url(redis_url)
        else:
            logger.debug('redis not configured')

    return _redis_store
```

On the main app, to queue a task:

```
from rq import Queue
from tools import get_redis_store

redis_store = get_redis_store()

queue = Queue(connection=redis_store)

def _slow_task(param1, param2, paramn):
    # here I execute the slow task
    my_slow_code(param1, param2)

# when I need to execute the slow task
queue.enqueue(_slow_task, param1, param2)
```

There are multiple options to use redis on Heroku, depending on what you use, you could need to change the env variable REDIS_URL. The environment variable DYNO is checked to know if the code is running on Heroku or in a developer machine.

Comment: Well, thank you ! let me check it out ; )

Comment: Hey man yes I got it almost what you did and again thank you! but I'm having another problem actually the task that i want to push into the queue will be done with a object ***bot*** and this object needs a declaration first with `bot = Bot()` and `bot.login(username, pass)` . then I'm ready to call the function i defined `dofollow(uname)` [here ***uname*** = username which will be given as input by the user of web]. Into the function i used the predefined ***bot*** object. As you've written the ***worker*** script will start the task queue. I want my function to be declared on that script.

Comment: because i can't do the declaration `bot.login(username, pass)` more than one time otherwise the module[instanot] I'm using will block me . so it will be great if you tell me how to declare that into that ***worker*** script and also i want to declare the function ***dofollow(uname):*** into that file [in your case it's ***_slow_task(param1, param2)***] which you defined into the app.py file. is there any way to dp that

Comment: So as the final wish i want is -- ***worker*** consists of ***initialisation step** of bot, ***def dofollow(uname)*** and ***queue initialisation*** | and from the ***app.py*** file i want to push that task ***dofollow(uname)*** and the parameter ***uname***[I'll get it from my index.html]

Comment: Not sure, but maybe you can initialize your bot before call the queue, and pass the bot as a parameter to the queue

Comment: yes that's what i need I'm trying this one : )

Comment: what if i want to pass only the ***args*** because my function will be always the same can i do something like i don't need to push the function to the queue by default it will be pushed the function as i mentioned before ***dofollow()*** with the ***arg*** I'll give

Comment: You need pass the function and the args to the queue, as in the example that I added